# Lower semicontinuous of Minkowski functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $P(x)$ is Minkowski functional of $C$ which is closed convex set and $\theta \in C$. After proving
$$
C=\{ x: P(x)\le 1\}
$$
and for any $\alpha >0$, $\alpha C$ is closed, how to get $P$ is lower semicontinuous  ?

I think the lower semicontinuous is
$$
\liminf\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0} P(x)=P(x_0).
$$
I can't see any connection between the lower semicontinuous and closure of $\alpha C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(1).  Show that for any $λ>0$, the set $\{ x \in X \colon P(x) \leq λ\}=λC $.

(2). Conclude that the sublevel sets $ L_λ= \{ x \in X \colon P(x) \leq λ\} $ are closed, for every $λ>0$. This is equivalent to saying that $P$ is lower semicontinuous.

Comment: I can prove the (1). But I can't get the (2). Namely, I can't prove that the closure of sublevel sets is  equal to $P$ is lower semicontinuous.

Comment: Take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646904/lower-semicontinuity-equivalence