# Ask some steps in the proof of compact+upper semicontinuous imply maximum?

Tags: real-analysis

If X is compact and $f : X → (−\infty, \infty)$ is upper semicontinuous, prove that $f$ attains
its maximum at some point of $X$.

Proof:

The sets $f^{−1}((−\infty, \alpha))$ are open for all $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$; hence, by compactness, there are finitely
many that cover X, and hence $f$ is bounded.

In particular, we only need to take one such set.
Now let $\alpha = \sup\{f(x) | x ∈ X\}$. Since $f$ is bounded, thus this $\alpha$ must $< \infty$. We claim that $f(x) = \alpha$ for some $x \in X$.

From here, I don't understand the proof.

If not, then we can
find some sequence $\alpha_n$ such that $0 < \alpha−\alpha_n <
1/n$. **(Question: is this because X is compact?)**
In particular, the sets $f^{−1}((−\infty, \alpha-1/n))$cover
X, **(Why?)** and there is no finite subcover, which is a contradiction. Hence f attains its maximum at
some point of X.

Comment: It's simpler if you use the sequential characterization of  upper semicontinuous functions; $f$ is upper s.c. iff $x_n \to x_0$ implies $\limsup f(x_n)\le f(x_0)$. Now take a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)\to \sup f$, etc...

Comment: But I prefer to use this topological setting.

Comment: @Mariana: I added more details to your argument. It is an interplay of compactness and properties of upper-semicontinuous functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative proof that may give some light to what you were describing in your posting.

For any $c\in A:=f(X)$ define $F_c=\{x\in X: f(x)\geq c\}$. Since $f$ is upper-semico0ntinuous, $F_c$ is closed (why?) The collection $\{F_c: c\in A\}$ has the finite intersection property; hence, $P:=\bigcup_{c\in A}F_c\neq\emptyset$. Any $z\in P$ is a maximal point of $f$ since for any $x\in X$, and $z\in P$
$$f(x)\leq f(z)$$

---

Here is a proof along the lines of your posting:

As you pointed out, $U_a:=\{x\in X: f(x)<a\}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$, forms an open cover of $X$ an account that $f$ being upper-semicontinuous, and $f$ being real-valued. The compactness of $X$ implies that there is $X=U_a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$ (why?). Let $\alpha:=\inf\{a\in\mathbb{R}: X=U_a\}$. Notice that $\alpha$ is an accumulation point of $A=f(X)$ and $f(x)\leq \alpha$ for all $x\in X$ (why?) Hence, there a sequence $x_n\in X$such that $f(x_n)\rightarrow\alpha$. As $X$ is compact, there is a subsequence $x_{n'}$ that converges to some $x^*\in X$. The upper-semicontinuity of $f$ implies that
$$\alpha=\lim_{n'}f(x_n')=\limsup_{n'}f(x_{n'})\leq f(x^*)\leq \alpha$$
This shows that $x^*$ is a maximal point of $f$.

---

Comment: In the second proof I present, I used the following equivalence regarding upper semicontinuous functions:

> Let $f:X\rightarrow[-infty,\infty]$ be a function on a Hausdorff topological space. $f$ is upper semicontinuous iff for any net $x_d\rightarrow x$, $\limsup_d f(x_d)\leq f(x)$.

A proof for this (actually for lower semicontinuous) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3646933/121671). The upper semicontinuous case follows by applying the result in that link to $-f$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your proof. But I can understand the original proof that I posted. Except the questions I asked.

Comment: Which part you don't understand?  $F_c$ is closed: this is because $\{x\in F: f(x)<c\}$ is open for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ on account of $f$ being upper-semicontinuous.  $\{F_c:c\in A\}$, where $A=f(X)$, has the finite intersection property: this follows from the fact that $F_c\neq\emptyset$ for each $c\in A$, and for any $c_1,\ldots,c_n\in A$, $\bigcap^n_{j=1}F_{c_j}=F_{c^*}$ where $c^*=\min_{1\leq j\leq n}c_j$. $P=\bigcap_{c\in A}F_c\neq\emptyset$: this follows from the fact that in a compact space, a family of closed sets with the finite intersection property has nonempty intersection.