# (X,d) be a metric space. $F: X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$. $F$ is sequentially lower semicontinuous iff $F$ is lower semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf, semicontinuous-functions

**Let (X,d) be a metric space. $F: X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$. $F$ is sequentially lower semicontinuous iff $F$ is lower semicontinuous**

The definitions that I have to use are:

**(1) $F$ is  sequentially lower semicontinuous if for all sequences $(x_n)_n \subseteq X$ s.t $ x_n\to x$ , $\liminf_n F(x_n)\ge F(x)$**

**(2) $F$ is   lower semicontinuous if $\forall x \in X$ and $t \in \mathbb{R} $ with $F(x)>t$, there exists  $r>0$ s.t $F(y)>t$ for all $y\in B(x,r)$**

I have already proven $(1) \implies (2)$ by contradiction

I am having trouble proving  $(2) \implies (1)$
I tried using contradiction as well , but I got nowhere:

If by absurd (1) is false, it means it's negation holds:

$\exists x_n \to x$ s.t $\liminf_n F(x_n)< F(x)$.

Since between two distint real numbers there's always a third one:$\exists t \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t

$\liminf_n F(x_n)< t <F(x)$.

So using (2), $\exists r>0,$  s.t $F(y)>t$ for all $y\in B(x,r)$

$\liminf_n F(x_n)< t <F(y) $,for all $y\in B(x,r)$.

Then I tried using that  the last inequality implies $F(x_n)< t <F(y)$, for infinitely many $n$'s
. I also tried using the definition of $\liminf_n$, but nothing. How should I proceed? Maybe contradiction is not the way to go here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lower Semicontinuity Equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646904/lower-semicontinuity-equivalence)

Comment: Actually I needed to finish my argument using (2) as given. Yours uses sublevel sets which is actually another question I've already proven using (2) but nevertheless it is useful to see how to do it using (1) instead

Comment: But you accepted @geetha290krm's proof below, which imo is identical to that in the proposed duplicate (first part: "Necessity") (apart from a commented misprint there, which will probably soon be corrected).

Comment: Isn't that one using that G is seq lower semicontinuos iff $\{G\le y\}$ is closed? 'Cause I don't think they are using (2) there. Actually  I had to prove separately that (2) holds iff  $\{F\le y\}$ is closed

Comment: i.e. they are taking $\{F\le y\}$ is closed as the definition of lower semicontinuity

Comment: No: the first sentence in [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646904/lower-semicontinuity-equivalence) is (when the misprint will be corrected) is: "For any $\alpha<f(x)$ the set  $V=\{f<\alpha\}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$", which is exactly the same as the first sentence below "$F(x) >t$ so there exists  $r>0$ s.t $F(z)>t$ for all $z\in B(x,r)$" , and the rest of the proof is also identical.

Comment: @AnneBauval Your help would be much appreciated here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695733/f-is-lower-semicontinuous-iff-fx-sup-r0-inf-y-in-bx-rfy-for-all  : )

Comment: I made a typo in my previous comment. Please replace $V=\{f<\alpha\}$ with $V=\{f>\alpha\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x) >t$ so there exists  $r>0$ s.t $F(z)>t$ for all $z\in B(x,r)$. We can take $z=x_n$ for $n$ sufficiently large. So $F(x_n) >t$ for such $n$ which implies $\lim \inf F(x_n) \geq t$, a contradiction.

Comment: I was almost there : ) !. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if I have to consider a separate case when $F(x)=-\infty$ or $+\infty$. In both implications I haven't

Comment: @some_math_guy The argument I gave works in all cases.