# $F$ is lower semicontinuous $\iff F(x)=\sup_{r>0}\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y)$ for all $x\in X$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf, semicontinuous-functions

Let (X,d) be a metric space. $F: X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$.
The definitions that I have to use are:

**(1) $F$ is  sequentially lower semicontinuous if for all sequences $(x_n)_n \subseteq X$ s.t $ x_n\to x$ , $\liminf_n F(x_n)\ge F(x)$**

**(2) $F$ is   lower semicontinuous if $\forall x \in X$ and $t \in \mathbb{R} $ with $F(x)>t$, there exists  $r>0$ s.t $F(y)>t$ for all $y\in B(x,r)$**

**(3) It holds  $F(x)=\sup_{r>0}\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y)$ for all $x\in X$**

**I have already proven  $(1)\implies (3)$ and  that $ (1)\iff (2)$ I have to prove  $(3)\implies (1)$:**

My tries:

I want to proof that $F(x) \le \liminf_n F(x_n)=\sup_k\inf_{n>k}F(x_k)$.
Take $x_n \to x.$

**try 1:**
I have tried to use the definition of $\sup$ in (3):

Calling $\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y):=\alpha(r)$

$\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists \alpha_{\varepsilon}(r)$ s.t  $ 
 F(x)-\varepsilon < \alpha_{\varepsilon}(r) \le F(x) $

... no clue if this is helpful

---

**try 2**

Since $x_n \to x$, for large $n, x_n \in B(x,r)$, so $\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y)\le F(x_n)$, for large n.
Then taking the sup over $r>0$: $F(x)=\sup_{r>0}\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y)\le F(x_n)$   and taking the $\liminf $ over $ n$:

$F(x)\le \liminf_n F(x_n)$

**This looks correct to me, but I am unsure,specially when taking the sup and then the liminf, maybe it's not allowed? It feels too easy, what do you think?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt is not quite correct, for sloopiness on quantifiers. Let us make it rigorous.

Since $x_n\to x$ we have
$$\forall r>0\quad\exists N\quad\forall n\ge N\quad x_n\in B(x,r).$$
Therefore,
$$\forall r>0\quad\exists N\quad\forall n\ge N\quad F(x_n)\ge\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y)$$
or equivalently
$$\forall r>0\quad\exists N\quad\inf_{n\ge N}F(x_n)\ge\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y).$$
This implies
$$\forall r>0\quad\sup_N\inf_{n\ge N}F(x_n)\ge\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y),$$
which is equivalent to
$$\liminf F(x_n)\ge\sup_{r>0}\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y).$$
This proves $(3)\implies(1).$ However, it is much easier to prove $(3)\implies(2)$: assume
$$t<F(x)=\sup_{r>0}\alpha(r),\quad\text{where}\quad\alpha(r):=\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y).$$
By definition of $\sup,$
$$\exists r>0\quad t<\alpha(r)$$
and by definition of $\alpha,$ the conclusion follows.

Comment: After the third step, why can't I just take the sup over r  and then the liminf without splitting it into sup and inf as I did? I just avoided writting "$\exists N \forall n\ge N$" by writting "lor large n".

Comment: Is the suggestion in the other answer also possible? I was thinking the negation of (1) is: $\exists x_n \to x s.t  \liminf F(x_n)<F(x)$. Then use the property that this implies $F(x_n)<F(x)$ for infinitely many n's. Now I am not sure if I can say that these $x_n$'s are a subsequence? Otherwise I don't see how I could extract a subsequence and anyway why  would  a subsequence be useful for?

Comment: Answer to your 1st comment: your  first "for large $n$" depends on $r.$ So, "$\alpha(r)\le F(x_n)$ for large $n$" does not imply "$\sup_{r>0}\alpha(r)\le F(x_n)$ for large $n$".

Comment: Answer to your 2nd comment: yes, a subset of $\Bbb N$ is infinite iff it is the range of a strictly increasing infinite sequence. (Here, the subset to consider is $\{n\in\Bbb N\mid 
 F(x_n)<F(x)\}$.)

Comment: but I just found I bunch of x_n's that are <F(x), why would they be ordered in a sequential manner, and moreover be  strictly increasing? I need to prove that  $x_{n_k} <x_{k_{n+1}}$

Comment: It is not the $x_n$ which are ordered. It is the $n$'s belonging to that "bunch". They are naturally ordered, and become the indices $n_k$ of your subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}.$

Comment: wait isn't  a sequence of real numbers  increasing if the values increase, aren't they? the n's are the domain, that's always in order like n^2 for instance. I guess the sequence $(x_n)_k:=y_k$ being in an abstract space may not have an order, but then considering the F((x_n)_k)=z_k, this a sequence of real numbers, the k's are in order, but the z's are not.  On another hand if I have a bounded sequence I can extract a convergent subsequence, which may be what I need here , but not sure what for

Comment: I agree with everything except the last sentence (and except that you wrote $(x_n)_k$ instead of  $(x_{n_k})_k$). This is precisely what I explained in my 2 previous comments (please re-read them). As for the last sentence, it is useless, and even [false for instance in an infinite dimensional normed vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma#Some_consequences) ([Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) holds for *compact* metric spaces).

Comment: Ok, then the subsequence I have extracted, can not be called increasing or decreasing , correct? Nor the sequence of real numbers $F(x_{n_k})$? So we only have a subsequence, can we say if it is convergent?The answer above says yes, but why? and why do I need this subsequence for?

Comment: *the answer below

Comment: What is increasing is the "extracting sequence" of indices $n_k$, no other sequence. For every sequence $(y_n)$ in $\overline{\Bbb R},$ the set of all possible [limits of those subsequences which do have a limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequential_limit) (possibly $\pm\infty$) is closed and nonempty, and its smallest and largest elements are respectively $\liminf y_n$ and $\limsup y_n.$ So: there exists a subsequence $(y_{n_k})_k$ which tends to $\liminf y_n.$ This should suffice you to understand the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easier when argued via contradiction, i.e. assume that (a) fails, then you can extract a subsequence which converges to a value strictly lower than $F(x)$. Now the subsequence is eventually in every neighborhood of $x$. Use this and the claim should follow.

Comment: I'll try that. Look at my recent edit in "try 2", do you thik that works?

Comment: Why can you extract a subsequence that converges?