# Property of lower semicontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf, semicontinuous-functions

I am trying to prove that f is sequentially lower semicontinuous at x if and only if $f()=\sup_{r>0}\inf_{y \in B(x,r)}f(y)$.

Following the proof of ([$F$ is lower semicontinuous $\iff F(x)=\sup_{r>0}\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}F(y)$ for all $x\in X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695733/f-is-lower-semicontinuous-iff-fx-sup-r0-inf-y-in-bx-rfy-for-all)), I can understand the $<=$ implication but I cannot prove the converse direction.

For general function it holds $f(x)\geq \sup_{r>0}\inf_{y \in B(x,r)}f(y)$. So I need to show that if f is lower semicontinuous, then it holds
$f(x)\leq \sup_{r>0}\inf_{y \in B(x,r)}f(y).$

Since for $x_n\to x$ it holds $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\geq f(x)$, it would suffice to find a sequence $(x_n)_n$ for which $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = \sup_{r>0}\inf_{y \in B(x,r)}f(y)$.

Comment: I am a bit confused, what is your definition of lower semicontinuous? You seem to ask why $f$ being lower semicontinuous implies $$\liminf_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x)=f(x_0).$$ This would be my definition.

Comment: The definition of lower semicontinuous that I am using is the following. If $x_n\to x$, then $\liminf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) \geq f(x)$

Comment: Ok, but if $\vert x_n-x\vert\leq r/2$, then $$f(x_n)\geq \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y).$$ Then you are done as $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y)=\sup_{r>0} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y)=f(x).$$

Comment: This is fine to prove that if $f()=\sup_{r>0}\inf_{y \in B(x,r)}f(y)$, then f is lower semicontinuous. I need to show the other direction.

Comment: No, this proves that $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)\geq \lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y)=f(x),$$ which is what you are asking.

Comment: So your approach is the following: Let $r_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $r_n\to 0$, and $x_n$ a sequence in $X$ such that $x_n\in B(x,r_n/2)$. Then $f(x_n)\geq \inf_{y\in B(x,r)}$ for each $n$. But then I have $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) \geq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \inf_{y\in B(x,r_n)}f(y)$. My only concerns regards the last part. Since $f$ is not continuous but only lower semicontinuous, how can I argue that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \inf_{y\in B(x,r_n)}f(y) = f(x)$?
It seems trivial, but we do not use the lower semicontinuity...

Answer (score 1):

If $\sup_{r>0}\inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y)=f(x)$, then $f$ is lower semicontinuous at $x$. Let $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n=x$. We define $r_n:=\sup_{m\geq n} \vert x _n -x \vert$. Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} r_n=0$. Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) 
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \inf_{m\geq n} f(x_m)
\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \inf_{y\in B(x,r_n)} f(y) \\
&=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y)
=\sup_{r>0} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y) =f(x).
\end{align*}

Now let's show the other direction. Namely, let $f$ by lower semicontinuous at $x$, then $\sup_{r>0}\inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y)=f(x)$. We have $\sup_{r>0} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y)\leq f(x)$ (this holds for every function), thus, we are left to show that $\sup_{r>0} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y)\geq f(x)$.

As $r\mapsto \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y)$ is a decreasing function, we get
$$ \sup_{r>0} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \inf_{y\in B(x,1/n)} f(y).$$
For every $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ pick $x_n \in B(x,1/n)$ such that
$$ \inf_{y\in B(x,1/n)} f(y) \leq  f(x_n) \leq \inf_{y\in B(x,1/n)} f(y)+ 1/n. $$
Then we have by the squeeze theorem
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \inf_{y\in B(x,1/n)} f(y) = \sup_{r>0} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y). $$
However, as we assumed that $f$ is lower semicontinous at $x$ we get
$$ f(x)\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = \sup_{r>0} \inf_{y\in B(x,r)} f(y). $$

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sharon_puthuparambil Glad I could help. If you have any question please let me know.

Comment: @Saverin Schraven Could the same statement be proved also for topological spaces? Namely that if $F$ is sequentially lsc, then $F = \sup_{V\in N(x)} \inf_{y\in V} F(y)$, where $N(x)$ denotes the set of all possible open neighbourhoods of $x$ ?

Comment: I do not know about the general case, but we can run the same proof if our topological space is first countable, i.e. it admits a family $(U_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that for every $U\in N(x)$ there exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $\ell\geq m$ holds $U_\ell\subseteq U$. In this case pick $V_n\in V(x)$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \inf_{y\in V_n} F(y)=\sup_{V\in N(x)} \inf_{y\in V} F(y).$$ Inductively we pick $\ell_1<\ell_2<\dots$ such that $U_{\ell_n}\subseteq V_n$. As the infimum gets only bigger if we shrink the set, we get [cont.]

Comment: [Cont.] $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \inf_{y\in U_{\ell_n}} F(y)= \sup_{V\in N(x)} \inf_{y\in V} F(y).$$ Now pick $y_n \in U_{\ell_n}$ and note that $y_n \rightarrow x$ (we could have assumed that $U_n\subseteq U_{n+1}$, otherwise consider $\bigcap_{\ell=1}^n U_\ell$ which yields such a family). Let $V\in N(x)$, then there exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $U_m\subseteq V$ and hence (as $\ell_m\geq m$) for all $k\geq m$ we have $$y_k\in U_{\ell_k} \subseteq U_{\ell_m}\subseteq U_m\subseteq V,$$ which gives us the convergence. [Cont]

Comment: [Cont] The convergence worked for any choice of $y_n\in U_{\ell_n}$. We now choice $y_n$ so that $$\inf_{y\in U_{\ell_n}} F(y)\leq F(y_n)\leq \inf_{y\in U_{\ell_n}} F(y) +1/n.$$ Then we get $$F(x)\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F(y_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \inf_{y\in U_{\ell_n}} F(y)=\sup_{V\in N(x)} \inf_{y\in V} F(y).$$

Comment: If you want to work in completely general (say Hausdorff) topological spaces, then you will probably need to work with nets instead of sequences (then you can run again essentially the same proof).

Comment: @sharon_puthuparambil Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Saverin Schraven Thanks!! I think this works. I am applying this result on a setup where $f$ is defined on probability measures on a compact space. This space is endowed with the initial topology induced by the maps $\mu\mapsto \int f(x) d\mu(x)$ where $f$ is a continuous function. Would this space be first countable?

Comment: @sharon_puthuparambil Typically weak-$*$ topologies need not be first countable. You might need to work with nets.